# Spring IDE install = Mylyn ? JIRA && Atlassian : la dolce vita ;

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, spring-ide

I have both Eclipse 3.5 and 3.6 on ubuntu 10.04. I am trying, actually attempting to install Spring IDE.

As usual, I install plug-ins on my galileo first before doing it on helios in case things break, since I actually use helios while galileos mostly languishes unused on my workstations. Which, in hind-sight (don't know why some people use the phrase hind-site), was a smart move, because I am stuck now.

As you can see, from my dry humour, I am rather frustrated now. So, pardon me for any unpardonable words or phrases that I might have used here. Here is my La Dolce Vita sequence of philandering with various eclipse update sites:

At [help: install new software] using [http://springide.org/updatesite], I selected all the choices to install. Have you ever wondered why [install new software] is under [help] menu because [help:install new software] does not actually provide any "help" documentation on installing software. It does not "help" you resolve all the missing requirements or where to find them.

The response was " ... cannot complete ... " and then took a long long long time generating a reason why it could not be completed even though I have a quad core 6gb machine. The reason was " ... mylyn feature not found ... ".

Then, I reduced my installation selection to only the three core items, and after a long^3 time, the reason for " ... cannot complete ... " was " ... mylyn something else ..." not found.

So I diverted the install to galileos update site and installed every mylyn item I could find. I had to restart eclipse. Then I went back to using springide update site to attempt installing only the top three core. This time, after another long^3 while, the reason for incompletability was " ... mylyn jira feature not found ...".

So I woogled and googled for "eclipse mylyn jira connector" which led me to Spring web site which makes some *foreign key* references to JIRA. At some point a site suggested that I installed http://download.eclipse.org/tools/mylyn/update/e3.4 to get jira???. I did as advised, and nope still " ... jira feature not found ..."

Somehow, surprisingly, when I googled "wtf is eclipse mylyn jira connector?" it pointed me to a site advising " jira has moved to atlassian ....". At that point, I was wondering ... why do i have to prefix expletives in my google search expression to get a useful answer?

To cut this episode of the story shorter, I installed every gastronomic item atlassian update site had to offer on the menu. I had to restart eclipse.

Still when tried installing Spring IDE again, just the top three items, the incompletability reason was again " ... jira feature not found ... ".

But if I selected every item to be installed, the incompletability reason was " ... something something eclipse ajdt not found ...".

At this point I have two crucial questions for which I need answers:

- Is there a complete list of whatever I need to install and where to find them, in order to complete my Spring IDE installation successfully?
- Should I trust Spring technology to be able to provide a hassle free route to mvp/mvc automation, if they cannot even provide comprehensive, useful and workable instructions on how to install their product? iow, Should I bother with Spring? Or, should I continue my current menial/manual method?

And a trivial question: When installing modules, netbeans resolves all the requirements for me, why doesn't eclipse?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_dolce_vita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, I found, lies in downloading the 187MB IDE installer from springsource.org, which has respective downloads for Eclipse 3.5, 3.6, 32 bit, 64 bit, Windows, Mac and Linux.

Like scala IDE, Spring IDE is hardcoded to certain Eclipse Platform micro release. Even though my Eclipse has the same release and down to the same release date and time, the micro-release identification was different from the one required/specified by the spring updates.

Therefore, even though SpringSource documents two ways of getting Spring IDE,

1. one by providing an update url for
   your current Eclipse
2. download SpringSource's own Eclipse
   IDE as a whole kabootle.

Method 1 is workable if you already had a previous Spring IDE installed.

Thousands apologies to SpringSource for my road rage.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I bother with Spring?

Yes, absolutely.

You don't need Spring IDE to get use out of Spring.  If you're just learning Spring, why pile learning an IDE on top of it?

I'd put Spring IDE aside for now and just learn Spring itself.  It's well worth the effort.  Once you're familiar with it, move on to the IDE.